# Angularjs ngInit repeats 3 times - ngClick once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there are a lot of other questions covering this topic, but none really answer my question.  I have a function that retrieves data from my db.  Now when i run the function on `ngInit` the function runs three times, but on an `ngClick` it only runs once, which is what I want.

I read in a couple of posts that it is normal for the function to repeat multiple times, because of the `angular watchers` that watches for the code to change.  Now I really don't mind that the code is repeating, but the issue is that I set a variable to `true` when the function starts and to `false` when I get the data.  But now my variable gets set to `false`, and the code runs again.  So my variable gets changed prematurely.

Example:

```
controller.getItem = function(){
    controller.loading = true;
    service.getSelectedItem($routeParams._id).then(function(response){
        if(response.data.state === 'success'){
            controller.myItem = response.data.item;
            controller.loading = false;
        }
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="item">
<!-- remove this comment to test ngInit -->
<!-- <div id="item" ng-init="controller.getItem()"> -->

    <button id="clickMe" ng-click="controller.getItem()">Get data</button>

    <div class="panel panel-new">

        <div class="panel-header">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h4>My Item - {{ controller.myItem._id }} 
                    <small>added on: {{ controller.myItem.dateAdded | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}</small></h4>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- Close div for .row -->

        </div> <!-- Close div for .panel-header -->

    </div>

</div>
```

Now my loading screen disappears and my content is still `undefined`.  Only after running three times does the content actually get populated.

As I said, when this function runs on an `ngClick` it works perfectly and only runs once, but on an `ngInit` it runs 3 times and does not work as intended.

I am not sure how to approach this issue.

Comment: can you share a little bit more code like how you are calling getItem ?

Comment: I just call it via a ng-init="controller.getItem()" or ng-click="controller.getItem()"

Comment: is ng-init inside ng-repeat?

Comment: nope, not at all.  It is on a new view, on the very first div.

Comment: share your html  as well!

Comment: You should avoid `ngInit`. [Check the documentation, and see if your usage falls within the three appropriate use cases](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). And even then, in most cases you can still find better alternatives. I only ever use `ngInit` for aliasing properties withing `ngRepeat` - and I do it very rarely.

Comment: I could recommend you to call an init function inside your controller instead of calling ngInit, as said @NikolajDamLarsen

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I added HTML

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I really don't want to call the function in my controller as the controller gets used for other functions too.  But I did test it, and it yielded same results.  I am not declaring my controller more than once.

Comment: In any case, `ngInit` is not the answer. If you reuse the controller multiple places, then yes, it would be executed multiple times since controllers aren't treated as singletons. If the "state" is shared between different components of the application, you should move it to a service instead of the controller.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Thanks, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of debugging, I finally found the issue.  The problem was that I had this in my index page:

```
<div ng-if="auth" id="ngView" class="ngView">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what was I think was happening is that it created a view, ran the function, created a view, ran the function.  So that is why everything was happening more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please little bit more detail. It should be better you could use nginit inside specific controller. Once you calling particular controller then it will run perfectly according to behavior.